# Disabling cache on all browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, cross-browser

I'm using ASP.Net VB. I'm trying to disable caching throught the website because my client is having an issue that he needs to clear his cache in order to make the system work.

I put this bunch of code in my master's page page_load.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(True)
```

And access my cache in chrome here. chrome://cache/

The first question is, is this the right way of disbaling caching? Next is, I assumed that putting it on master page will have all pages be affected by this, is this a correct assumption? Lastly, how do I know if this code is working/if my browser is still storing cache to check if the code is right. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You'd surely be better working out why your client needs to clear his cache and fixing that.

Comment: Yeah. But omitting that scenario. Do you have any answers to my questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Things can work with only one line of code

```
 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

But it is good practice to delete the existing page from cache.

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

you can check that page is expired or not on page load

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            if (Page.IsPostBack)
             {
                    if (pageIsExpired()){
                       Response.Redirect("/Some_error_page.htm");
                    }
                    else {
                       var now = Now;
                       Session("TimeStamp") = now.ToString();
                       ViewState("TimeStamp") = now.ToString();
                    }
        }
}



      private boolean pageIsExpired()
      {
         if (Session("TimeStamp") == null || ViewState("TimeStamp") == null)
            return false;

         if (Session("TimeStamp") == ViewState("TimeStamp"))
            return true;

            return false;
      }
```

Source :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11225/Disabling-browser-s-back-functionality-on-sign-out

Comment: I tried this code and put it on my master page and click back. The page is still there.

Comment: yes mate, page will be there you are only disabling the cache not the stoping the page to be render again.

Comment: So placing them on the master page on load is fine? Thanks!