# Clearing/Disabling browser cache ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

For the record, does this code clear or disable cache?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1))
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

If yes, does this disable the broweser's cache? or server cache? If no, what is the right way of clearing the browser's cache. Again, browser's cache.

I also found this code.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in HttpContext.Current.Cache){
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(string(entry.Key));
}
```

Does this delete browser's cache? My goal is to clear my browser's cache in my login.aspx. Thanks!

Comment: To disabling cache on all browser, Solution is <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183282/disabling-cache-on-all-browser">here</a>

Answer (score 2):

[Response.Cache.SetNoStore()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setnostore.aspx) tells the browser not to cache the page by setting http header "Cache-Control" to "no-cache". So the browser knows that is should not cache this response.

[HttpContext.Current.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) on the other hand is server side caching. You should store things there that are common for all users of the application.